# Lock Adjacent cell if cell contains certain text

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

I am trying to adapt the following code to lock adjacent cells when Column M contains "NO"

For example if M12 contains "NO", I would like to lock "V12:AG12,AI12:AT12"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim c As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("M:M"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

For Each c In rng1
    Select Case LCase(c.Value)
        Case Is = "YES"
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
        Cells(c.Row, 13).Resize(1, 12).Locked = False
        Range(Cells(c.Row, "V"), Cells(c.Row, "AG")).Locked = False
        Range(Cells(c.Row, "AI"), Cells(c.Row, "AT")).Locked = False
         ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
    Case Is = "NO"
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
        Range(Cells(c.Row, "V"), Cells(c.Row, "AG")).Locked = True
        Range(Cells(c.Row, "AI"), Cells(c.Row, "AT")).Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
    Case Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
        MsgBox "Please only input YES or NO in this column", vbCritical +   vbOKOnly
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
        Exit Sub
End Select
Next c

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
End Sub
```

However I am confused to **where i would insert the condition "NO" in the above code and also how to select the range to "Lock"**

Attached a picture to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be doing what you want :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim c As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M:M"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
Me.Unprotect Password:="Password"

For Each c In rng1
    Select Case LCase(c.Value)
        Case Is = "yes"
        Me.Cells(c.Row, 13).Resize(1, 12).Locked = False
        Me.Range(Me.Cells(c.Row, "V"), Me.Cells(c.Row, "AG")).Locked = False
        Me.Range(Me.Cells(c.Row, "AI"), Me.Cells(c.Row, "AT")).Locked = False
    Case Is = "no"
        Me.Range(Me.Cells(c.Row, "V"), Me.Cells(c.Row, "AG")).Locked = True
        Me.Range(Me.Cells(c.Row, "AI"), Me.Cells(c.Row, "AT")).Locked = True
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Please only input YES or NO in this column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
End Select
Next c

Me.Protect Password:="Password"
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Note that I've also included lines to unlock the cells that would be locked by a "NO" so that they can be unlocked if you change back the value to "YES"

Comment: Thanks for looking at this so quickly! Much appreciated, The lock function does not seem to be working I think it is to do with my Worksheet being protected I have ammended your code slightly, however it still fails to lock the adjacent cells when condition is "NO"  Please see ammended code (in the orginal question).. Do you have any further Ideas of how to get this to work?

Comment: Ok, I added the password protection too (no need to place it everywhere) and as this module is a sheet module, you should rather use `Me.` than `ActiveSheet.`. Also be careful in your code you used `NO` and `YES` for the test but we test `LCase(c)` so it'll only be lower case.